# How can I search exact List match in solr list field

Tags: list, solr, field

For example, 
I've list field(solr.TextField) in my schema store list of values like follows

1) { fruits : ["Apple","Mango","orange"] }

2) { fruits : ["Mango","Apple"] }

I've keyword list for search is: ["Apple","Mango"]

What is the query that can get exact list match that contain only given all values "Apple","Mango".

Here it should give me second document.i.e.,  { fruits : ["Mango","Apple"] }

I've tried to using fruits : ( "Apple" "Mango" ), but it doesn't work,
It giving me both documents.

Comment: Are you able to modify schema? If yes, one hackish solution could be a keeping count for multivalue fields, so for doc1, it will be two fields, {fruits : ["Apple", "Mango", "Banana"], fruits_count: 3}
When you do query against two values mango and apple, you also provides extra condition fruits_count: 2 or whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple boolean query `(fruits:Mango AND fruits:Apple)`

**Updated:**

```
(fruits:Mango AND fruits:Apple AND -fruits:orange)
```

Comment: It will match first document as well

Comment: For example:  (fruits:Mango AND fruits:Apple AND -fruits:orange).

Comment: Solving one particular case doesn't help to solve it in general. Do you need all possible values for mv field to build such query?

Comment: Thanks @Oyeme, But How I can eliminate all values in other documents.I will have only keyword list.
For example I have Other document have { fruits : ["Apple","Mango","banana"] }